# Вывод колонок из csv файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть csv файл - dataset.csv, он содержит две колонки с числа.
Подскажите как вывести обе колонки в виде вещественных чисел и чтобы первая колонка присваивалась переменной x, вторая колонка переменной y.
У меня получается выводить только одну колонку.

Файл: [dataset.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5fqh/3jmqPTc8H)

Код:

```
import csv

Sample=[]
with open("dataset.csv", encoding="ANSI") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V, delimiter=';')
    for col in SR:
        Sample.append(float(col[0]))
print(sorted(Sample))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep=";", header=None)
x = df[0].astype("float").values.tolist()
y = df[1].astype("float").values.tolist()
```

в переменных x и y теперь соответственно списки первой и второй колонок:

```
# x:
[48.0,
 66.0,
 52.0,
 70.0,
 60.0,
 110.0,
 140.0,
 139.0,
 105.0,
 95.0,
 85.0,
 88.0,
...

#y:
[22.0,
 14.0,
 19.0,
 19.0,
 16.0,
 16.0,
 13.0,
 13.0,
 19.0,
 18.0,
 16.0,
 15.0,
 17.0,
 17.0,
 16.0,
 17.0,
...
```